# no body on email from cfmail

Tags: email, coldfusion, cfmail

I have this code that is sending an email to me when some query is running on database from coldfusion. I'd receive the email without problems but there is no body on it, only shows the subject. I tryed using no type on cfmail tag and changing the cfmailpart tag type="html" for type="text", but nothing happens. The funny thing is that in my local folder CF8/mail/undelivr i can see the body of the email and shows itself without problems, but when this code go to production, doesn't work. Some clue about what is happening?

this is the code i'm using now:

```
<cfset fechaActual = dateformat(Now(),"dd-mm-yyyy") >
<cfset horaActual = TimeFormat(now(), "HH:mm:ss") >
<cfset archivoActual = CGI.http_host  & CGI.script_name & "?"  & CGI.query_string>

<cfmail type="html" to="xxx@xxx.com,xxx@xxx.com,xxx@xxx.com" from="xxx@xxx.com" subject="Delete tabla xxx #fechaActual# hrs.">
    <cfmailpart type="text">
        Este aviso indica que ha sido ejecutado un DELETE en la tabla xxx.

        Hora de ejecución: #horaActual#
        Fecha de ejecución: #fechaActual#
        Ruta:D:\xxx\xxx\xxx\xxx\xxx.cfm
        Url: #archivoActual#
        Linea: xx
        IDs Eliminados: #idaviso#
    </cfmailpart>
</cfmail>
```

Thank you!!!
best regards

Comment: you don't need to use `cfmailpart` you can just put your content inside the `cfmail` tags

Comment: i'm already try that but the the problem continues. Thank you

Comment: gmail, i'm using the navigator, firefox to be specific

Comment: If you are seeing mail in the Undelivr folder then something else is wrong. Mail only goes to that folder when ColdFusion cannot deliver it to the mail server.

Comment: yes, the undelivr folder  is only for local test. In production the email is send it without problem, but is send it without the body of the message.

Comment: Now is working!!!... the file without cfmailpart is sending to me an email with the body. I was confusing because there is another file doing the same thing, and that file wasn't modificated. thank you Matt Busche and all of you guys for your time :).

Answer (score -2):

I suggest using both text and HTML cfmailparts. Including both increases the probability that they will be readable by everyone. You might want to make the text only cfmailpart very basic with limited information.

Be sure to include text only within the text cfmailpart and HTML formatted text in the HTML cfmailpart.

```
<cfmail type="html">
    <cfmailpart type="text">
        Este aviso indica
    </cfmailpart>
    <cfmailpart type="html">
        <p>Some HTML words</p>
    </cfmailpart>
</cfmail>
```

Comment: He is sending it to himself.

Comment: there was no need to use cfmailpart, thanks anyway :)